# How to make sure a file is loaded from disk only once by multithreads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

There is a file which could be access by multithreads in random order, how to make sure the file is loaded from disk only once to reduce file io costs in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: Static, threadsafe map over file names to their streams/memory mapped representations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
private final Map<File, byte[]> cache = new HashMap<File, byte[]>();

public synchronized byte[] readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = cache.get(file);
    if (content == null) {
        content = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        cache.put(file, content);
    }
    return content;
}
```

**UPDATE**

this version is supposed to allow asynchroneous reading

```
private final Map<File, byte[]> cache = new HashMap<File, byte[]>();
private final Map<File, Object> locks = new HashMap<File, Object>();

public byte[] readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    Object lock = getLock(file);
    synchronized (lock) {
        byte[] content = cache.get(file);
        if (content == null) {
            content = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            cache.put(file, content);
        }
        return content;
    }
}

private synchronized Object getLock(File file) {
    Object lock = locks.get(file);
    if (lock == null) {
        lock = new Object();
        locks.put(file, lock);
    }
    return lock;
}
```

Comment: You will not be able to read asynchronously with this, which could be a drawback.

Comment: @Ryan Amos I agree in principle, but when it's about reading files, synchronization overhead may be not essential, see BufferedInputStream, all its methods are synchronized, while the class is designed to improve file reading efficiency

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev BufferedInputStream will read a file synchronously, which it should. Individual files should not be read asynchronously. However, my point is that multiple files cannot be asynchronously read. If you try, Evgeniy Dorofeev's method will lock until the previous file finishes reading, even though both files could be read simultaneously.

Comment: Could use a ConcurrentHashMap to enable reading multiple (different) files at once.

Comment: 'File' is probably not a good hash key since it's not a "simple, immutable" object.  I'd opt for f.getCanonicalPath() instead.

Comment: +1 good design.  Separate locks are used for separate files so each can run concurrently.  (only getLock() has to briefly sync).  When someone opens a file for the first time it gets a lock and blocks others waiting for that file.  However once cached there should be minimal contention.

Answer (score 0):

well you could keep track of the files your are currently accessing...

```
public static final long FILE_LOCKED = -1;

private static Set<File> lockedFiles = new HashSet<File>();

private byte[] fileContent;

private synchronized boolean acquireFileLock(File file) {
    if(lockedFiles.contains(file) {
        return false;
    }

    lockedFiles.add(file);
    return true;
}

public long readFile(File file) {
    if(acquireFileLock(file)) {
        // read your File into fileContnent
        lockedFiles.remove(file);
        return bytesRead;
    } else {
        return FILE_LOCKED;
}
```